# How to make typescript repo work when installed in javascript project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, babel-loader

I have created a repo that contains some files in javascript and some in typescript it works fine. but when I installed this repo into another project which is purely javascript in that case when I import any file which is written in typescript I get the error Unable to resolve the path to module 'myRepo/sum'.

**NOTE:** The app which is consuming myRepo could not setup typescript, it should work with myRepo changes

**Solution Tried:** added postinstall hook as tsc but that doesn't work

sharing my package.json which is fetching myRepo written in js and ts

```
    {
  "name": "test-repo",
  "private": true,
  "sideEffects": false,
  "scripts": {
    "test:jest": "npx jest",
    "build:dev": "BABEL_ENV=development webpack --config webpack/webpack.dev.js",
    "build:devWatch": "BABEL_ENV=development webpack --watch true --config webpack/webpack.dev.js",
    "start:dev": "nf start & npm run build:dev"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.4",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-async-generators": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^7.10.4",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-regenerator": "^7.10.4",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.13.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.4",
    "@babel/register": "^7.10.4",
    "@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss": "^2.3.0",
    "@tanepiper/robots-webpack-plugin": "^0.4.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.5",
    "babel-eslint": "^9.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^23.4.2",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node": "^2.3.3",
    "babel-plugin-root-import": "^6.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-source-map-support": "^2.0.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-imports": "^1.5.1",
    "babel-preset-airbnb": "^5.0.0",
    "cssnano": "^4.1.10",
    "cypress": "^4.12.1",
    "cypress-image-snapshot": "^3.1.1",
    "cypress-log-to-output": "^1.0.8",
    "dotenv": "^6.2.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.4.2",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.2.0",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.3.4",
    "eslint": "^5.3.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.11.1",
    "exports-loader": "^0.7.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
    "html-loader": "^1.3.2",
    "html-loader-jest": "^0.2.1",
    "http-proxy": "^1.17.0",
    "http-server": "^0.11.1",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^7.0.1",
    "imports-loader": "^0.8.0",
    "js-yaml": "^3.13.0",
    "postcss": "^7.0.27",
    "postcss-cli": "^6.1.3",
    "postcss-custom-properties": "^9.1.1",
    "postcss-import": "^12.0.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.4.2",
    "serverless": "^1.50.1",
    "serverless-finch": "^2.4.2",
    "serverless-offline": "^5.8.0",
    "serverless-plugin-common-layers": "^1.0.0",
    "serverless-plugin-tracing": "2.0.0",
    "string-replace-loader": "^2.2.0",
    "svg-url-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.3",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.2",
    "url-loader": "^2.2.0",
    "webpack": "^4.29.6",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.1.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.2.1",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "^2.0.4",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.2.1",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.7.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "airbnb-browser-shims": "^3.3.0",
    "jest": "^25.1.0",
    "myRepo": "git+ssh://git@github.com:githUser/myRepo.git#master",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2",
    "react-google-recaptcha": "^2.1.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^6.15.4",
    "react-hook-inview": "^4.3.8",
    "react-loadable": "^5.5.0",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.5",
    "rollbar": "^2.4.1",
    "sanitize-html": "^2.3.2",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.16",
    "style-loader": "^1.2.1",
    "uuid": "^3.3.3",
    "validator": "^13.5.2",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^2.0.4",
    "xss-filters": "^1.2.7"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the response/error for better understanding?